# AJAX request not returning data from PHP class

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX request very similar to the one pasted below and works to fetch data and then .html() into the assigned id. However, I'm not sure why the same method won't work twice.

If I hard code the object and then `echo $answer->site();` For some reason, it appears for a moment and then disappears.

jQuery:

The one that works:

```
$('#start').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "questionHandler.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {question:"1"},
        success: function(data) {
            $("#furtherdetails").remove();
            $("#question").html(data);
        }   
    }); 
});
```

The one that doesn't work:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "answerHandler.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {answer:"site"},
        success: function(data) {
            $("#answer").html(data);
        }
    });
```

PHP:

```
public function site() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM answers WHERE qid = 1 AND sub_answer IS NULL";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    if(isset($_POST['answer'])) {
        foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $answer) {
            echo '<td>';
            echo '<input style="display: inline-block;" id="answers" type="radio">'.$answer['answer']. '<br>';
            echo '<label for="answers">' .$answer['answer']. '</label><br>';
            echo '</td>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is with how you're calling `loadSite()`. Maybe you're not preventing the default form submission so the page is reloading.

Comment: I edited the question a bit. But in regards to having it as `loadSite()` I've also tried having just the AJAX call by itself inside `#start.click()` because I want the questions and answers to appear at the same when `#start` has been clicked.

Comment: Check the Network tab of DevTools to see what's being returned.

Comment: The answerHandler and the page I'm supposed to be using `html()` on. The `answerHandler.php` file only includes the php file that contains the php code I've posted and just some db connection stuff.

Comment: I've looked into the `questionHandler.php` in the Network tab and it returns what I want it to return but `answerHandler.php` was just blank.

Comment: Then there's a problem in the script. Does it actually call the `site()` function?

Comment: No but the working one wasn't calling the `question()` function either and it works.

Comment: Functions don't run by themselves, you have to call them. Unless you're using a framework that calls functions automatically.

Comment: I'll look into this and also into why the `questionHandler.php` works.

Comment: I've found out where the issue is: it's only posting `question: '1'` but not `answer: 'site'` even if I've added that onto the same call. Why is that?

Comment: No idea, I don't see any problem with your `$.ajax` code.